# JSON output returns null using PHP ajax

Tags: php, ajax

When I view the record from the database, the result is displayed as `null`.

This is what I tried so far:

```
<?php
    include("db.php");
    $fetchqry = "SELECT mid, planid, paid_date, expire_date FROM payment";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $fetchqry);
    $num = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    { 
        $mid = $row['mid'];
        $planid = $row['planid'];
        $date1 = $row['expire_date'];
        if (strtotime(date("Y/m/d")) < strtotime($date1)) 
        {
            $status = "Active"; 
        }
        else 
        {
            $status = "Expired";
        } 
    } 
    echo json_encode($row);
?>
```

Comment: The loop ends when `$row` is `NULL`. What are you expecting `json_encode($row)` to be after the loop is done?

Comment: `while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { ... }  echo json_encode($row);`. When you've done fetching the results, `mysqli_fetch_array` returns null. That's why you get `null`

Comment: What are all the variables that you set in the loop for?

Comment: record  should set look like this format          $output1[] = array ("mid "=>$mid );  like wise as json array

Comment: Then you should use `json_encode($output1)`

Comment: i jsut create the variable $output1 and encode the json data as ("mid "=>$mid format how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the values you read from the DB to an array, then encode that.

```
$output = [];
$today = strtotime(date("Y/m/d"));
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{ 
    $mid =   $row['mid'];
    $planid = $row['planid'];
    $date1 = $row['expire_date'];
    if($today < strtotime($date1)) 
    {
        $status = "Active"; 
    }
    else 
    {
        $status = "Expired";
    }
    $output[] = ['mid' => $mid, 'planid' => $planid, 'status' => $status];
} 

echo json_encode($output);
```

Comment: thanks you sir workinggggggggggggggggggggggggg.